# Ionic: JavaScript heap out of memory while doing "ionic serve"

Tags: javascript, windows, ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic5

I am working on a Ionic 5 project. While doing ***ionic serve*** getting error as:

```
"FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"
```

I had tried below command but getting same error again if I rerun the project

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8096
```

What other solution we have for this?

Comment: What node version are you using?

Comment: Node version: 12.19.1

Comment: Can you try upgrading to the latest LTS and check again?